# upload to S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to Elastic Beanstalk, just uploaded an NodeJs app.
I'm wondering if it's possible to "link" (like unix symlinks) a folder to a S3 bucket?

Make "/recordings" points to S3:

```
var filename = 'recordings/' + match[1] + '.wav';
      var file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
      var request = https.get(url, function(response) {
          response.pipe(file);
          file.on('finish', function() {
            file.close();
      }).on('error', function(err) {
        fs.unlink(file);
        console.log('error downloading recording');
      });
```

Comment: No, it's not possible, as S3 is not a file storage, rather an object storage (Amazon calls it storage for the internet) and its meant to be be managed via its REST API (or SDKs which use the REST API under the hood) so it doesn't have file system capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use tools like [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) to mount S3 buckets to your filesystem. However, this is generally not recommended as S3 is not designed to be used as a block storage device.

As the s3fs readme documents:

> Generally S3 cannot offer the same performance or semantics as a local
>   file system. More specifically:
>
> - random writes or appends to files require rewriting the entire file
> - metadata operations such as listing directories have poor performance
>     due to network latency
> - eventual consistency can temporarily yield
>     stale data no atomic renames of files or directories
> - no coordination
>     between multiple clients mounting the same bucket
> - no hard links

The best way to use S3 with your Node application is using the [AWS SDK for JavaScript in Node.js](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/).